# Error cloning a git repository (can't open pageant program)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've opened a repository on github, and am now trying to clone it using TortoiseGit 1.5.3.0. I'm getting these cryptic error:

```
can't open pageant program
git have not installed
```

When I'm trying to follow the instructions on github, I'm getting the following error after doing "git commit -m 'first commit'"

```
error: pathspec 'commit'' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

**Edit**

Trying to diagnose, this is what I've done:

1. Reinstalled latest Tortoise Git
2. Tried to create a local repository. Got this helpful box:

[image]

Next, I tried clearing my personal data from Tortoise, and reentering my username & password. Got the same lovely error window.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a restart (after the reinstallation) solved it :(

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Can you use git smoothly "locally" (i.e. no pushes etc.). Then we can be sure that it's installed and working fine.

Second, can you make sure that pageant (I believe that's an ssh-keyring) is installed and working fine? Maybe you can try sshing into github to see it that works. See [here](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/) for details.

Once these two are working fine, we can go ahead. If this is tortorise-git specific, I can't really offer any advice since I've not used it.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem you need to use double-quotes for grouping when on a Windows system. Single quotes don't mean anything special to Windows/DOS:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```